# VS2019, Version 16.9.4. Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Win32.Primitives, Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid

Tags: vb.net, .net-core, console

I making simple console application with NET CORE. Finally my application can started a couple of day ago, but not in NET CORE 3.1 as I need, only in NET CORE 5.0.
Today I continue develop my application, add NewtonJson library, add main application logic. This is my project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>LinuxCamelCase</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>My Project\app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MySqlConnector" Version="1.3.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />

  </ItemGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <Import Include="MySqlConnector" />
  </ItemGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Unfortunately my application stop working with error message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Last time I saw this 'bad image format' it related to having selected 'x86' in place of 'x64', or vice versa in Target CPU.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Very thank you. This is solution !!!

Answer (score 0):

As @AndrewMortimer said above, solution is

```
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
```